# Each loop with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout, scrolltop

I would like create a JS Each loop scrolltop in featured elements with waiting the animate is ended then waiting before to execute next. This is the prototype code with 3 elements :

```
      open_el = $('#0-article');
      setTimeout(function() {
        page.animate({
          scrollTop: open_el.find('.player').offset().top
          }, 'slow', function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
              open_el = $('#10-article');
              page.animate({
                scrollTop: open_el.find('.player').offset().top
                }, 'slow', function(){
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    open_el = $('#1-article');
                    page.animate({
                      scrollTop: open_el.find('.player').offset().top
                      }, 'slow', function(){
                    });
                  }, 2000);
              });
            }, 2000);
        });
      }, 1000);
```

Here I wait 1000ms before to scrolltop to #0-article element, then after I wait 2000ms to scrolltop to element #10-article etc ...
how I can done it with a loop ?

```
$('.featured').each(function(){
   ...
});
```

thanks

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML/CSS

Comment: HTML/CSS is like a isotope mansory wall with articles elements

Comment: If you add a class to the elements you want to auto-scroll to or add the selectors of the article cards my post below should handle it.

Comment: yeah it works perfect in your code, but in my code its a bit different and complexe because isotope mansory need to be builded before, so it needed to run the next ScrollTop section to the end of the animate function.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the workground with recursive function :

```
var featured = [];

function scrollTopToFeatured(i) {
  if (i === 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      page.animate({
        scrollTop: $('#'+featured[i-1]).offset().top
        }, 'slow', function(){
          scrollTopToFeatured(i - 1);
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
}

$('.featured').each(function() {
  featured.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

scrollTopToFeatured(featured.length);
```

Thanks Guys